# Как работает Play Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Объясните, почему Гугл не банит таких разработчиков, которые воруют одни игры и присваивают другие, а если я картинку какую то залью левую, то мне предупреждение кидают?

[К примеру этот разработчик](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.games35cm.bounce)

Comment: А почему вопрос к нам, а не, например, к Гуглу?

Comment: @VladD, А ты задай вопрос им, они молчат по этому поводу, сразу видно что акк нет у тебя там

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что если разработчик(истинный) имеет какие либо права(патент) на эту игру и подаст в суд, то гугле обязательно решит вопрос(забанит).
А на счет картинок - просто такая политика для всех. Да и зачем заливать в гугле плей всякие картинки, к которым можно придраться?

Comment: Чувак, но почему другие то могут так делать? Чем я то хуже их, что они там с гуглом за ручку ходят, ноги лижут им чтоли из за этого им разрешенно использовать чужие картинки.

Не ну ты глянь в Play Markete. Набери Anime, 70% приложений используют чужой контент и ведь их не банит никто